# How can I close vim's parent terminal from within vim?

Tags: key-bindings, terminal

I am trying to close the terminal window directly from vim.

The final purpose of this is to have a command (shortcut) that opens VSCode in the current directory from vim (when I need a GUI editor) and closes my terminal window.

Comment: Hi Welcome to Vim. Would be nice if you could explain us what you did try and why it doesn't work the way you want

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt I actually did not find any way to do it, so for the moment I haven't try a solution yet, I am looking for one

Comment: so `:exit` in the terminal prompt does not close your :terminal window?

Comment: Maybe you just want to start VsCode with ``:!code`` and skip the utilisation of the terminal.

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt yes I would like something like that but that closes the terminal window after launching VSCode

Comment: @gruvw if you do not need the terminal, use `:!command`. If you need the terminal, consider using `:command` and after that using `exit` to close the terminal. You possibly also need to use `disown` so that closing the controlling terminal does not close vscode. This could be put into a script/alias.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt closing a terminal that launched VSCode won't close the app. When I write `:!code .` it opens VSCode correctly but then vim stays open in my terminal. What I want is a way to close the terminal from which vim is running after opening VSCode (or after the execution of whatever command I ran `:!command`. Something like `:!command; exit` (which does not work).

Comment: Do I understand correctly, that you want to have vim and the terminal in which it runs also closed? In that case, you need to use manually quit Vim first and then close the terminal.

Answer (score 1):

I propose to:

- Start vim using a script.
- Launch VsCode using:
  On Windows I propose you to use:

  `:execute '!start code "%:p:h"' | cquit 2`

  or on Linux:

  `:execute '!code "%:p:h" &' | cquit 2`
- Detect the return code 2 in the script that launch vim to kill the parent terminal.

Comment: First of all, I am on Linux. Second, there seems to be a misunderstanding of the question: I am looking for a way to close the terminal running vim, the VSCode part is just to give some context. I know I can write `:!code .` to open VSCode but I need the terminal running vim to close after opening VSCode (or after executing any other command)

Comment: You want a command that: 1. start VsCode , 2. close vim and 3. close the terminal that started vim. Do I have the correct understanding?

Comment: Yes, however, your current solution does not close the terminal (step 3). And as I already said, I just need a way to close the terminal window running vim from within vim. Drop the VSCode part, it was just to give some context.

Comment: I see no ways in Vim. I would be you I would starts vim with a script, use ``cquit`` instead of ``qall`` to quit vim and detect the return code in the script to kill the parent terminal.

Comment: Yes I thought about that but the issue is that I don't know when I start vim if I will want to start VSCode later on... The rest of the time I don't want vim to close the terminal when I exit. Is there a way to pass some data to the bash script that launched vim ? Then the shell script could know when to exit the terminal after hearing back from vim and when not to.

Comment: That is why I propose ``:cquit`` instead of ``:qall``. The first make vim returns a non zero code and the later a zero code that can be leveraged.